# How do I show this : $0<c_k < \frac{1}{p^{k-1}}$ for $h(t)= a+\sum_{k\geq1}c_{k}t^k$ ,$k\geq1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

let $h$ be a function defined in the neighborhood of $t=0$ with this formula: 
$$h(t)= a+\sum_{k\geq1}c_{k}t^k$$  with $a=1+p >1$ , $h$ satisfy the following functional equation: 
$$h\bigl(\frac{t}a \bigr)h'(t)=ah'(at)~,$$
My question here is :

> How do I show this  : $0<c_k  < \dfrac{1}{p^{k-1}}$, $k\geq1$ ?

Comment: You cannot show that $c_k>0$, because the constant function $h(t) = a$ is a solution to this functional equation.